Missing Value in data
Working with Weather_trends in 2023. I need to find out any relationship with Wind Speed and Visibility. But there are missing entries in the table Wind Speed and Visibility. What is the Query to get sorted out in the BigQuery?
SELECT
Weather_trends
WHERE
CAST(Wind Speed as a INT),
CAST (Visibility as INT)


A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Please learn how to ask proper question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Try something like below:
SELECT
  CAST(Wind_Speed AS INT) AS Wind_Speed,
  CAST(Visibility AS INT) AS Visibility
FROM
  `<your-project-dataset-name-here>`
WHERE
  Wind_Speed IS NOT NULL
  AND Visibility IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  Wind_Speed, Visibility;

